# Breadcrumb menu update on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, breadcrumbs

Currently, this is all I have in terms of code for this:

```
<a href="#"> 1 > </a>
```

This `<a>` link will probably need some changes, since ideally the user could click on the number and revert to that question number.

and 2 buttons

```
<input class="btn btn-success NavigationButtons" id="BackButton" type="submit" name="Previous" value="Back" />    
<input class="btn btn-success NavigationButtons" id="ForwardButton" type="submit" name="NextPage" value="@Session["ForwardButtonText"]" onclick="RadBtnValidation()"/>
```

So what I need, is every time the user clicks the button with `id="ForwardButton"` is for the `<a href="#"> 1 > </a>` to change to `<a href="#"> 1 > 2 > </a>` and vice versa whe the user clicks the back button. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/363). It shows an example of how to build a custom HTML helper that could work for your scenario, but as I pointed out there, you may need to be more specific about what the "ForwardButton" will do in order to implement the logic correctly for your use case.

Comment: Save your visited pages in an array. The array should be managed in the `click` functions of the buttons: remove last item for `BackButton` and add new item for `ForwardButton`. After that, both functions should call another function i.e. `LoadBreadCrumbs`. That function should do nothing else than loop the items in the array and add them to the _anchor_ element's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store numbers and append they inside a every button click.

```
var numberList = [];
init();
function init(){
    numberList.push(1);
    ShowNumber();
}
$("#BackButton").click(function(){
    numberList.pop();
    ShowNumber();
    });
$("#ForwardButton").click(function(){
    numberList.push(numberList[numberList.length-1] + 1);
    ShowNumber();
});
function ShowNumber(){
  $("#txtPageNumber").html("");
  for(var i=0; i<numberList.length;i++)
  {
     $("#txtPageNumber").append(numberList[i] + ">");
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gnne36nw/1/